# How to populate a list in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

Say you have the following predicate:

```
random_int(X/Y):-
  random(1,100,X),
  random(1,100,Y),
  X\=Y.
```

How can I populate a list of size n using the result of this predicate?

I tried the following code but it only populates the list if random_int(X) is true at the first attempt, i.e. it does not backtrack to try other combinations of X and Y.

```
findall(X,(between(1,N,_), random_int(X)),L).
```

Comment: I don't think you can populate a list using that exact predicate? Because sometimes it fails ...  unless you built something that tried to see if it failed and if it did tried it again..

Comment: So what you've changed your question to mean is that you want your list filled with *unique* random numbers? And do you need your predicate that fills such a list to succeed only once, or do you need it to allow backtracking, continuing to find more such lists?

Comment: Go ahead and look at SWI-Prolog's `library(random)`: http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=random

Answer (score 2):

I find this small 'application' of clpfd interesting:

```
?- N=10,M=12, repeat, findall(X, (between(1,N,_),random(1,M,X)), L), clpfd:all_different(L).
N = 10,
M = 12,
L = [5, 4, 6, 7, 9, 11, 2, 3, 8|...] 
.
```

note: M *must* be > N

Comment: That's a nice, tidy way to do it. And it serves as a generator rather than a one-shot success. (+1) This concept could be applied to either the `findall/3` method or the `maplist` based solution I showed in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I guess a simple way to do it is to make a list of 1:100, and draw 100 times from it a sample of size 2, without replacement. Since this is Prolog and not R, you can instead do:

```
:- use_module(library(lists)).
:- use_module(library(random)).

random_pairs(Pairs) :-
    findall(X/Y,
        (   between(1, 100, _),
            randseq(2, 100, [X,Y])
        ), R).
```

This is available in SWI-Prolog at least, but it is free software and the source to `randseq/3` is available on the web site.

And since it's better to not use `findall` unless strictly necessary, it would probable better to write:

```
random_pairs(Pairs) :-
    length(Pairs, 100),
    maplist(randseq(2, 100), Pairs).
```

or, if the `X/Y` is important,

```
random_pairs(Pairs) :-
    length(Pairs, 100),
    maplist(rand_couple(100), Pairs).

rand_couple(N, X/Y) :-
    randseq(2, N, [X,Y]).
```

**TL;DR** Use the available libraries

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with `findall/3`:

```
random_list(N, L) :-
    findall(X, (between(1,N,_), random(50,100,X)), L).
```

Another tidy way to do this would be:

```
random_list(N, L) :-
    length(L, N),
    maplist(random(50, 100), L).
```

Which results in:

```
| ?- random_list(5, L).

L = [69,89,89,95,59]

yes
| ?-
```

In general, if you have a predicate, `p(X1,X2,...,Xn,Y)`, and a list you want to fill with result `Y` using successive calls to `p/(n+1)`, you can use `length(List, Length)` to set the length of your list, and then `maplist(p(X1,...,Xn), List)` to populate the list. Or, using the `findall/3`, you can do `findall(X, (between(1,N,_), p(X1,...,Xn,X)), L).`.

---

**EDIT** based upon the updated conditions of the question that the generated list be unique values...

The `random` predicates are not generators, so they don't create new random numbers on backtracking (either unique or otherwise). So this solution, likewise, will generate one list which meets the requirements, and then just succeed without generating more such lists on backtracking:

```
% Generate a random number X between A and B which is not in L

rand_not_in(A, B, L, X) :-
    random(A, B, X1),
    (   memberchk(X1, L)
    ->  rand_not_in(A, B, L, X)
    ;   X = X1
    ).

% Generate a list L of length N consisting of unique random numbers
%    between A and B

random_list(N, L) :-
    random_list(N, 50, 100, [], L).
random_list(N, A, B, Acc, L) :-
    N > 0,
    rand_not_in(A, B, A, X),
    N1 is N - 1,
    random_list(N1, A, B, [X|A], L).
random_list(0, _, _, L, L).
```

Yet another approach, in SWI Prolog, you can use `randseq`, which will give a random sequence in a range `1` to `N`. Just scale it:

```
random_list(N, A, B, L) :-
    A < B,
    Count is B - A + 1,
    randseq(N, Count, L1),
    Offset is A - 1,
    maplist(offset(Offset), L1, L).

offset(X, Offset, Y) :-
    Y is X + Offset.

?- random_list(5, 50, 100, L).
L = [54, 91, 90, 78, 75].

?-
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 random_len([],0).
 random_len([Q|T],N)  :-
    random(1,100,Q), 
    random_len(T,X), 
    N  is  X+1.
```

Comment: You can use random(50,100,X) if you want it to be between 50 and 100